# Why does QDrag::target() return a strange address after QDrag::exec()?

Tags: c++, qt

I have created two `QCustomListWidget`.in the qt designer by promote `QListWidget`.The drag and drop between them works well, but when I call `QDrag::target()`after a successful `QDrag::exec()`it returns a strange address that does not equal the target `QCustomListWidget`. Also,`QDrag::source()`'s return is correct.

Here is the simplified code.

```
class QCustomListWidget:public QListWidget 
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit QCustomListWidget(QWidget* parent = 0);

    protected:
        void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
        void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
        void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
        void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event);
        void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);

    private:
        void StartDrag();

        QPoint m_eventstartpos;
};

QCustomListWidget::QCustomListWidget(QWidget* parent) : QListWidget(parent)
{
    setAcceptDrops(true);
}


void QCustomListWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        m_eventstartpos = event->pos();
    }

    QListWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void QCustomListWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) 
    {
        int distance = (event->pos() - m_eventstartpos).manhattanLength();
        if (distance >= QApplication::startDragDistance())
        {
            StartDrag();
        }
    }
}

void QCustomListWidget::StartDrag()
{
    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
    //
    // ...set mimedata...
    //

    QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
    drag->setMimeData(mimeData); 

    Qt::DropAction da;
    da = drag->exec(Qt::MoveAction);
    if (da == Qt::MoveAction)
    {
        QObject* s = drag->source(); // s is correct
        QObject* t = drag->target(); // t is an strange address
        QCustomListWidget* targetlw = qobject_cast<QCustomListWidget*>(drag->target()); // targetlw == nullptr

        qDebug() << drag->target(); // output: QWidget(0xa1bef0, name = "qt_scrollarea_viewport")
    }
}

void QCustomListWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    QObject* src = event->source();
    QCustomListWidget *sourcelw = qobject_cast<QCustomListWidget *>(src);
    if (sourcelw && sourcelw != this)
    {
        event->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
        event->accept();
    }
}

void QCustomListWidget::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
    QObject* src = event->source();
    QCustomListWidget *sourcelw = qobject_cast<QCustomListWidget *>(src);
    if (sourcelw && sourcelw != this)
    {
        event->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
        event->accept();
    }
}

void QCustomListWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    QObject* src = event->source();
    QCustomListWidget *sourcelw = qobject_cast<QCustomListWidget *>(src);
    if (sourcelw && sourcelw != this)
    {
        // process data

        event->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
        event->accept();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Strange" how? Dump it out `qDebug() << drag->target()` and tell us what you see. *Note: Reply to an issue with the question by editing the question, not commenting. This is not a discussion forum.*

Comment: @KubaOber : I have added debug codes and finally know the issue.'QDrag::target()' returns the list widget's child widget named 'qt_scrollarea_viewport'.Thanks a lot.And...What should I do to the question now?

Comment: Ideally, you should revise it (`target()` doesn't return a strange address, but perhaps an unexpected object), and answer your own question, and accept your own answer after 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding simple debug codes

```
qDebug() << drag->target();
```

I get the answer.`qDebug()`'s output is

```
QWidget(0xa1bef0, name = "qt_scrollarea_viewport")
```

Actually `target()` returns the listwidget's child widget which named `qt_scrollarea_viewport` in this case.So `QDrag::target()` doesn't return a strange address, but perhaps an unexpected object.

Special thanks to @KubaOber.